# Program done how can I use it on other PCs?

Tags: c, exe

I just finished coding my c program in visual studio (VS) and what I had done is just drag the compiled .exe file out of the folder to run it on other computers, except on other computers for that to work I guess I need VS since it says the MSVCR110D.dll is missing which is from VS. So how can I run my program on other computers that don't have VS?

Comment: Change the build mode to Release.

Comment: And make sure that with your exe you copy any dlls that are referenced.

Comment: you could add the -static parameter to the link step, so all the libraries are part of the resulting file.   This will make the resulting .exe file significantly larger and on a different PC, some of the included libraries might not work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3w7axy17.aspx

In your output window it will show you where you can find the exe file, usually something like "ProjectName/Debug/Release/"

If you have added any external libraries you will have to copy any DLL files in that folder with the exe (You can combine them with some applications if needed)

You will also have to make sure that you have the correct version of the .NET Framework on the PC that you are trying to run your program on

Comment: Ah ok I got it, that wasn't bad :D Thanks for the help!

Comment: All the best and happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [IExpress](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-an-Exe-File) which is used for distributing self-contained installation packages. It is there in every windows machine preinstalled. Using this utility you can make the executable `.exe` which will be incorporated with dependent `dll`s. You can see [Step by step guide](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-an-Exe-File), to see how to use it.